# SQL - MYSQL One query recieving set limit on different column values

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say i have a table with a set of different columns (offcourse),

Example :

```
Table 
   id
   col1 INTEGER(1),   // 0 || 1
   col2 // --||--
   col3 // --||--
   col4 // --||--
```

Is it possible, in 1 query to select 4 rows where col1=1 and then select 4 rows where col2=1 and then select 4 rows where col3=1 etc etc. I think you understand what i mean.

What i have done so far is to make 4 different queries OR make one query and just do a (col1 = 1 OR col2=1 OR... etc).

This works but if i limit that result to lets say 16, then i might get 15 rows with col1=1 and maybe 1 row with col2=1 and then col3,col4 - no result.

So dear fellas; is there a way to do this in 1 query (i think not)

Comment: you can try to use `union` clause. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: This kind of problem is sometimes symptomatic of poor design

Comment: Hello! Yes i agree on that. The problem wasnt there to start with. Client needs, and integration of quick fixes resolved to a structure like this. I was however thinking of saving the query result to session so it didnt go through all that shit on each request. Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from table where col1=1 limit 4
Union
Select * from table where col2=1 limit 4
Union
Select * from table where col3=1 limit 4
Union 
Select * from table where col4=1 limit 4
```

This will get you one result with 16records max. If there are less then 4rows for a certin criteria, you'll get less rows. Duplicates will be removed, resulting in less then 16 rows. Not different rows.

If for a single row `col1=1 and col2=1`, then it might be returned twice if you use `union all`, but just `union` is slower with large datasets

Comment: Yes :) Good solution. I understand the cost. Thank you very much. I will try this out and test the speed. Maybe 4 different independent queries are faster. It depends.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `UNION ALL` construct. You may simply write

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col1 = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col2 = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col3 = 3
```

and so on. Just be aware of a fact that the rows may be duplicated in the result (if they satisfy more criteria from the conditions).

Comment: The answer from @HugoDelsing is better as it includes the LIMIT

Comment: Yes, and that is kinda a problem, but if we extend the query it might work. Thank you.

Comment: I would have marked this as solving the issue but as @JacquesAmar said, Hugos answer is a little bit closer, not because of the limit clause but of the Union explanation